# Parity check matrix of LDPC encoder and decoder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, error-correction

MATLAB provides powerful LDPC encoder and decoder objects in the latest versions. However the parity check matrix `H`, with dimension `(N-K)` by `N`, needs to satisfy the following condition:

> "The last `N−K` columns in the parity check matrix `H` must be an invertible  matrix in `GF(2)`"

Indeed, this condition is not easy to be satisfied for most LDPC codes, although we know that there is at least one `(N-M)` by `(N-M)` invertible sub-block in the parity check matrix   `H`,  if `H` is with a full rank.

I want to know that, if there exists a fast algorithm or a MATLAB function, which can find out an invertible sub-block in `H` provided `H` is with a full rank. So that we can use the MATLAB objects and Simulink blocks conveniently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried repermuting the columns of H matrix until it matches the Malab

```
% Programmer: Taha Valizadeh
% Date: September 2016

%% Column Permutation
% Permute columns of a binary Matrix until the rightmost square matrix is
% invertible over GF(2)

% matrix dimensions:
[~, n] = size(H);

% Initialization
HInvertible = H;
PermutorIndex = 1:n;
flag = true;
counter = 0;

% Initial Report
disp('Creating a ParityCheck matrix which is suitable for MATLAB COMM Tollbox')

% Permute columns
while flag

    % Check if the rightmost square matrix is invertible over GF(2)
    try

        EncoderObject = comm.LDPCEncoder(sparse(HInvertible));  
                                % Check if new matrix works
        fprintf(['ParityCheck Matrix become suitable for Matlab LDPC Encoder ',...
            'after ',num2str(counter),' permutations!\n'])
        flag = false;           % Break the loop

    catch

        % Choose different columns for the rightmost part of matrix
        counter = counter+1;    %Permutation Counter
        PermutorIndex = randperm(n);
        HInvertible = H(:,PermutorIndex);

    end

end
```

Comment: Sorry for that I see your answer so late. Thank you very much for your Matlab codes. I will try to run them. Indeed I used to encode the information symbols into an all zero codeword when I was doing the simulation. But this method does not always work.

Comment: This works. I used it in my project. The only catch  is that it reorders columns of parity check matrix  after permutations. If that's ok then your good.